# What is the best way to make same code of object for different use

Tags: kotlin, design-patterns, model

I have 2 model classes, both called `Assessment`. 1 for MainActivity and other for JourneyActivity. Both used for showing recyclerview. This is the code :

```
data class Assessment(
    val title: String,
    val imageUrl: String,
    var workouts: List<Workout>
)
```

I make 2 class with same code for different activity, is it a good way to *model designing*?

Comment: Same code in 2 classes is a sign of redundancy. Why dont you just put the common code into a base class and extend it if necessary?

Comment: [Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).